# Loading content in different levels

Tags: c#, static, xna

I am building an XNA game and I have used this method to create new levels.
First I make an abstract class called `Level`:

```
public abstract class Level {
    public abstract void Update(GameTime gameTime);
    public abstract void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch);
}
```

In the Game1 object, I declare a `public static Level currentLevel;`
and after initialising it (Like : `currentLevel = new GameLevel()`), call it's update and draw methods in the `Game1.Update` and `Game1.Draw`.  When I want to change the level, I do `Game1.currentLevel = new RandomLevel()`
I load my textures for all my levels in `Game1.LoadContent` by calling the `static Load` method in my levels.
My actual levels look like this:

```
class GameLevel : Level {

    Background sky = new Background(new Vector2(0, 0), -0.2f);
    Background land = new Background(new Vector2(0, 0), -0.2f);
    public static void Load()
    {
        ...
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**My problem:**
If my textures are static in the levels, I can load them in my static Load method which I call in the `Game1.LoadContent`. It works fine only if there are static textures(In fact, It works like that in my other levels). But in this level, I have a normal background objects. So I can't call `sky.Load` and `land.Load` in a static method. I want to create a lot of backgrounds with different textures. So how do I load the texture for my each of my background objects at the start of the `GameLevel`?
I was thinking of using a `DrawableGameComponent` and inherit it in `GameLevel` but I can't. Because I already inherited `Level`. I also got to know that `GameComponent`s are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a static `ContentManager` reference in `Game1`and assigned `Game1`'s `Content` to it. Then I used that content to load the texture for the `Background` object in the constructor of the `GameLevel` object. I didn't think it will work before because I thought the contents are only loaded once per game. (As it was written in the comments of the `LoadContent` method. It worked anyway.
If there is a better way to do it, please do tell me.